# Recursive Batch File

Tags: windows, batch, recursion, findstr

I have a file that looks this:

```
head1,head2,head3,head4,head5,head6
a11,a12,keyA,a14,a15,a16
a21,a22,keyB,a24,a25
a31,a32,keyC,a34
a41,a42,keyB,a44,a44
a51,a52,keyA,a54,a55,a56
a61,a62,keyA,a64,a65,a66
a71,a72,keyC,a74
some message
```

Objective: Write list of unique keys to a text file. For example, the result for the file described above should be:

keyA, keyB, keyC

Here's the pseudocode I would like to implement in batch file `recur.bat`

1. Read second line of inputfile
2. If no key exist on second line, return
   else continue
3. Append `keyX` to list
4. `FINDSTR /v keyX inputfile`
5. Pipe results to `recur.bat`

I don't know if this is the most efficient way to do this without using actual programming language.

Any suggestions for actual batch file code?

Comment: Welcome to Super User, MCZ! So, what's your question, really? Did you get stuck somewhere implementing the file? What have you come up with already? Also, please check the preview of your posts before submitting them – you need to indent code by 4 spaces or by pressing `Ctrl-K`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use PowerShell, which comes with Windows Vista or later:

```
$keys = @( );
Import-Csv input.txt | ForEach-Object { 
    if (!$_.head3) {
        $keys | Out-File output.txt;
        break;
    } else {
        if (!($keys -contains $_.head3)) {
            $keys += $_.head3;
        }
    }
}
```

This may be slow on large amounts of data, since it is using an array (`$keys`) to hold and check unique keys. An alternative method is to write everything into a text file, sort it, and run it through `Get-Unique`. Another alternative is to use a hashtable (wouldn't help with memory usage, but would be faster than checking if something exists in an array).

This uses `Import-Csv`, which will take the first line as the headings. It then passes an array of objects (lines) to `ForEach-Object`. `$_` is a variable referencing each object (line). `.head3` is the property with the name `head3`, as defined in your example data as the column containing the keys. It checks if there is a value for this column in this line; if not it outputs to a file and quits as per your pseudocode. **Note that non-key values may be accepted.** If you have/need stricter rules for what is a key, you can check length, or do some RegEx pattern matching, etc..

```
a71,a72,a73,a74
a71,a72,keyC,a74
some message
a71,a72,keyD,a74
```

Currently, `a73` counts as a key (it's in the third column, `head3`). The program will end at `some message`, since it does not have a third column, and will not read `keyD`.

If the line does have a key column, it checks if the key already exists in the array and, if not, adds it. **Note that `-contains` is case insensitive.** If this is a problem, it can be changed.

So you'll probably have to replace `input.txt` `output.txt` and `head3` with the correct names. This was the simplest solution that does not modify the order of the data, though faster ones are possible if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Separate answer because this is, essentially, a different solution</sup>

So, here's a cmd/batch version.

```
@echo off
type NUL>output.txt
for /f "tokens=1,3 delims=, skip=1" %%a in (input.txt) do (
    if "%%b"=="" goto :eof
    findstr "^%%b$" output.txt > NUL
    if ERRORLEVEL 1 echo %%b>>output.txt
)
```

It creates output.txt, then reads input.txt using `for` and `,` as a delimiter. The first line is skipped.

The first token (`tokens=1,3`) needed to be read to stop it on the `some message` line, since it would just skip the line and continue if the requested token (`tokens=3`) did not exist - and would never run the `if`. `%%a` is the first requested token (`1`), `%%b` is the second (`3`).

```
a71,a72,a73,a74
a71,a72,keyC,a74
some message
a71,a72,keyD,a74
```

`keyD` will not be read, since it stops at the line before (does not have a third token). However, `a73` will be counted.

This uses `findstr` on the output file to check if the key is already in there - not efficient at all, but it works. The RegEx is used to make sure it matches the whole line; if one key is contained entirely within the other key it won't match (i.e. `keyA` will not match `key`). Output is piped to `NUL` to keep things quiet.

And if the key is not in the output file, it will append it.

Answer (score 0):

In Bash (you can use Cygwin if you are on Windows) this is easy:

1.) replace , by newline (\n)

```
sed -i 's/,/\n/g' superuser.txt
```

Before you had:

```
head1,head2,head3,head4,head5,head6 a11,a12,keyA,a14,a15,a16 a21,a22,keyB,a24,a25 a31,a32,keyC,a34 a41,a42,keyB,a44,a44 a51,a52,keyA,a54,a55,a56 a61,a62,keyA,a64,a65,a66 a71,a72,keyC,a74
```

Now you have:

```
head1
head2
head3
head4
head5
head6 a11
a12
keyA
a14
a15
a16 a21
a22
keyB
a24
a25 a31
a32
keyC
a34 a41
a42
keyB
a44
a44 a51
a52
keyA
a54
a55
a56 a61
a62
keyA
a64
a65
a66 a71
a72
keyC
a74
```

2.) Search for "key", sort the results and eliminate duplicates

```
grep -F key superuser.txt | sort | uniq
```

Gives you:

```
keyA
keyB
keyC
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP's file wasn't in one line, they just got the formatting wrong. See the updated question.

Comment: Need to use native Windows commands.

Comment: keyX = a hexadecimal value (string)  ranging from 0000 to FFFF. Therefore, the word 'key' is not contained in any rows of column 3.

Comment: @MCZ Does that include PowerShell? because while this may be possible with `for` in cmd, PowerShell would definitely be 'cleaner'.

Comment: @Bob... Unfortunately I need to use commands that come with Windows. Any third party tools necesitates Admin privilges, which I dont have.

Comment: By the way, the files i'm working with are appeox 1/2 GB in size.

Comment: @MCZ PowerShell comes with Vista and newer.

Comment: @Bob... Will look into it. Haven't used PowerShell. I'm beginner at using batch files, don't know syntax for my solution. If I use PowerShell, what commands u recommend? General approach you would take? The most efficient solution I have so far takes about 15 seconds to read 500 MB file (using MATLAB textscan function)